# How to split the date and time in Python

Tags: python

My data set have the "Dates" column  like this"2003-01-06 00:15:00".I need to remove this "00:15:00"   and place the same in an another column named Time.How can we achieve that.Kindly share your thoughts.

Comment: This implies a lot of things - that you're using a database, for one, and that the dates *should* be separated.  I mean, if you have a table of nothing but times, then you're not going to really be able to correlate them to a specific *day*.  But...as your question's presented, you're kind of asking us to do the heavy lifting here, which isn't what we're here for.

Comment: Can you share your sample data

Answer (score 0):

To strictly answer, your question on how to extract the date from `"2003-01-06 00:15:00"`, You can split the string about the space, making it `["2003-01-06", "00:15:00"]`.  Then you grab the first element of the array `"2003-01-06"`.

```
"2003-01-06 00:15:00".split(" ")[0]
```

If this is all you needed help with, great; but if you're having a problem getting the date from your dataset, I would recommend posting some of your data with column names and sample entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> re_pattern_time = re.compile( r"(.*)\s+(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)$" )
>>> t = "2003-01-06 00:15:00"
>>> results.group(1)
'2003-01-06'
>>> results.group(2)
'00:15:00'
```

Comment: I forget the line   "results = re_pattern_time.match( t )"

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.